# Can't install new version of angular/cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've unistalled `angular/cli -g` but running `ng -v` shows me `angular cli: 1.6.2`
How is that possible? I'm not in a directory with `packakge.json` file or `node_modules` folder.

After installing `npm install -g @angular/cli` nothing changes. `ng -v` still returns `1.6.2`

I have `node: v8.11.2` and `npm: 6.0.1`

Screenshot:
[image]

Environment variables:
[image]

Comment: did you tried `npm cache clean` this command also ? I mean just try this one `[sudo] npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean`

Comment: tried `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: after doing cli uninstall do close the terminal and open it again. It may help you

Comment: Same result - I'm on windows - Added screen shot

Comment: So no local package folder (node_modules) in that directory?

Comment: run this `npm upgrade -g @angular/cli`

Comment: @Igor - no. Mohsin: It gave me nothing - I don't have @angular/cli globally installed.

Comment: I've added my env variables

Comment: To find the location of the file execute this: `where ng` , that should give you the folders where the `ng` command is found. Then you can track these down and delete them.

Comment: @Igor thanks it shows Yarn (I have both - don't know what for). I'll try to uninstall Yarn

Comment: @Igor it's working - thanks. Write anwser I'll mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the location of the file execute this: `where ng`, that should give you the folders where the `ng` command is found. Then you can track these down and delete them.

Comment: Thanks - it turned out that used yarn version instead of npm.

Comment: @piernik - glad you found the culprit.